# Android angle miscalculation in mapview

Tags: android, geometry, line, android-mapview

Normally in geometry rotation of angle starts from 0 to 90 in clockwise direction. I used the angle and mapview coordinates to draw on mapview. It draws line by assigning angle in anti-clockwise direction. How to change this, help to find an solution for this.

Using the angle I plot points in mapview to draw lines and connect them all to look like a polygon. I use each lines ending point as starting point of next line. It draws line in anti-clockwise direction. What helps to resolve it?

Thanks in advance..

This below image shows the problem.

http://tinypic.com/r/a0z9jn/8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subracting every angle from 360 it draws line correctly towards clockwise direction and my requirement is achieved.